# codeigniter mysql query group

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have a table 'categories' and 'items'

what i want to achieve is list 1 category and all items that have it. is it possible to use 1 query?

let's say:

**CategoryName**
*Item 1, Item 2*

here's a screenshot of my tables
[image]

[image]

currently this is the query im using which is obviously doesnt work

```
SELECT * FROM category as c, item as i WHERE c.restaurant_id = '7' GROUP BY c.category_id
```

and this is my foreach loop in my view

```
foreach($categories as $row){
        echo "<p>";
        echo anchor('dashboard/category/'.$row->category_id, $row->category_name);
        // *i want my item names listed here*
        echo "</p>";
    }
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want can you give your desired result like table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both the tables like

```
SELECT category_name as cat_name, item_name as item_name 
FROM categories 
JOIN items ON items.category_id = categories.category_id 
WHERE categories.restaurant_id = '7'  
GROUP BY items.item_id
```